# CTRL+C / CTRL+V don't work with PCManFM

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, lubuntu, pcmanfm

Sometimes the file browser of my Lubuntu OS(PCManFM) doesn't accept <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>  commands. I have to copy files using the mouse. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>  have this random problem as well; furthermore icons of files selected to be cut doesn't change (usually file browsers apply transparency to icons of cutting files).

I have not found a known open bug. Maybe keyboard is misconfigured?

Answer (score 0):

I occasionally run into this as well, though usually it works fine. Just to answer the transparency upon cutting aspect of it, I don't think that PCManFM does this at all.

Answer (score 0):

For me, disabling the Desktop icons in the `gnome-tweaks` program works as a workaround. The bug is [reported here](https://sourceforge.net/p/pcmanfm/bugs/1059/).

[image: Screenshot of gnome-tweaks]